# Room migration problem: foreign key as part of composite primary key

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am migrating a DB to a new version with 2 new tables added and getting this: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.` Thing is, I have incremented the version and have a migration for this, and it doesn't even tell me what I'm doing wrong like it usually does ("was expecting something-something"). I suspect the problem might be in the table where I'm using a foreign key as part of composite primary key, but according to SQLite documentation I'm doing everything right. What am I missing?

Pre-existing table I'm referencing:

```
@Entity
data class RailcarOnStationEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    var railcarId: Int = 0,
    ...
)
```

New table 1:

```
@Entity
data class BoolDictionaryResponseEntity (
    var createdAt: Long,
    var updatedAt: Long,
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int,
    var sysCode: String,
    var name: String
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return Gson().toJson(this)
    }
}
```

New table 2:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = [
    ForeignKey(
        entity = RailcarOnStationEntity::class,
        parentColumns = ["railcarId"],
        childColumns = ["railcarId"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )],
    primaryKeys = ["railcarId","dictId"])
data class BoolDictionaryResponseEntityRel (
    var railcarId: Int,
    var dictId: Int,
    var value: Boolean,
    var dictName: String
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return Gson().toJson(this)
    }
}
```

DB:

```
@Database(
    entities = [... RailcarOnStationEntity::class, ... BoolDictionaryResponseEntity::class, BoolDictionaryResponseEntityRel::class], version = 6
)
```

...

```
@Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: UserRoomDatabase? = null

        operator fun invoke(context: Context): UserRoomDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    UserRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "user_database"
                )
                    .addMigrations(..., MIGRATION_5_6)
                    .build().also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
        }
```

...

```
private val MIGRATION_5_6 = object : Migration(5, 6) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BoolDictionaryResponseEntity ('id' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'trainNum' TEXT NOT NULL, 'sysCode' TEXT NOT NULL, 'name' TEXT NOT NULL, 'createdAt' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'updatedAt' INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('id'))")
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BoolDictionaryResponseEntityRel ('railcarId' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'dictId' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'value' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'dictName' TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('railcarId','dictId'), FOREIGN KEY ('railcarId') REFERENCES RailcarOnStationEntity('railcarId'))")
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, I'm an idiot. I forgot to delete "trainNum" when I copy-pasted the query in one table, and forgot to add "ON DELETE CASCADE" in the other. Although I still don't know why I didn't get the usual exception. Oh, well. Moderators, feel free to delete this question.

Comment: Great!! So instead-of delete request, make this answer well documented, so it can help others too. And it is good to answer your own question, just improve it.

Comment: @PankajKumar It would've been useful if it hadn't been caused by a glorified typo :)

Comment: ahh okay, then try to delete it by yourself or flag it for moderators